# is there no way for Invoking Java Runtime Continuously? (without exiting Java Runtime)

Tags: java, c++, windows, command-prompt

i need to run Java Program in C++ code, so i tried it by below.

```
system ("java MyProgram1.class");
system ("java MyProgram2.class");
system ("java MyProgram3.class");
system ("java MyProgram4.class");
```

however, each overhead is very high, it works slow.
i suppose running Java Runtime in every call is very slow. (every about 50 seconds in my PC)

in my suppose, that step is..
    (1) Invoke System(...) Function -> (2) Run Java Runtime -> (3) Run My Java Program1 -> (4) Invoke System() Function -> (5) Run Java Runtime -> (6) Run My Java Program2 -> (7) Invoke System() Function -> ...

so, in Windows command prompt, is there no way for Invoking Java Runtime Continuously? (without exiting Java Runtime)

for example,

```
windows prompt> run JavaRuntime
--> Going to Java Runtime
Java> MyProgram1
Java> MyProgram2
Java> MyProgram3
Java> MyProgram4
Java> Exit
windows prompt> ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Java only exits when the program exits, just like in C++.

If you want Java to keep running, you need to not exit (just like in C++)

If you want to communicate with a running process you have to use some form of IPC/RPC/RMI (just like C++) or you can use files/pipes.

This is true of any process written in any language.

> i suppose running Java Runtime in every call is very slow. (every about 50 seconds in my PC)

A simple process takes about 0.1 seconds which is more than C++ but if you are doing it every 50 seconds it will waste about 0.2% of one CPU.